# How to check if generic type is nil

Tags: go

I have a generic function. I want to check if parameter provided is nil (and prevent it).

What is the best way to do it?

Here is a sample code:

```
func main() {
    Hello(1)
}

func Hello[T any](id T) {
    if reflect.ValueOf(id).IsNil() {
        panic("id cannot be nil")
    }
    fmt.Printf("Hello %v\n", id)
}
```

That code panics.

Comment: The program panics because an `int` cannot be `nil`.  Are you asking how to determine whether a value is the zero value for its type?  In this case, do you want to determine if `id == 0`?

Comment: I want to prevent caller of `Hello` to pass a nil value

Comment: Thanks, you may answer and I'll validate. Or maybe I should close question because already asked multiple times. I just did not thought of it well.

Comment: [The argument must be a chan, func, interface, map, pointer, or slice value](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect#Value.IsNil:~:text=The%20argument%20must%20be%20a%20chan%2C%20func%2C%20interface%2C%20map%2C%20pointer%2C%20or%20slice%20value). You need to check the kind of the argument first: https://go.dev/play/p/8tuCtWtCHDx

Answer (score 2):

The only types that can be nil are chan, func, interface, map, pointer, and slice.  Check for one of those types before calling IsNil

```
func Hello[T any](id T) {
    if v := reflect.ValueOf(id); (v.Kind() == reflect.Ptr ||
        v.Kind() == reflect.Interface ||
        v.Kind() == reflect.Slice ||
        v.Kind() == reflect.Map ||
        v.Kind() == reflect.Chan ||
        v.Kind() == reflect.Func) && v.IsNil() {
        panic("id cannot be nil")
    }
    fmt.Printf("Hello %v\n", id)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For pointers this works:

```golang
func isNil[T comparable](arg T) bool {
    var t T
    return arg == t
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/G9K3i28qGFX

Comment: This isn't a nil check -- this is a zero-value check. `isNil(0)` will return true, 0 is not nil.

Comment: 0 is the value of a nil pointer.  So you actually need `isNil(0)` to be zero.  If you are saying 0 is an integer, then yes, I said explicitly "For pointers this works".  The constant '0' is not a pointer nor an integer until it is assigned to a type.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "zero-value check" in Go.  When comparing values you need the 0 constant to be associated with a type.  If that type is a pointer, then it is known as the nil pointer.

Comment: My point was that there is a distinction between nil value and a zero value that this solution does not account for. Maybe that doesn't matter to you; totally fine/depends on your use case just pointing it out.

Comment: Which is what I said in my answer, "for pointers this works", which you have ignored.

Answer (score 1):

Adapted from anon's answer — checking for nils

```
func isNil[T any](t T) bool {
v := reflect.ValueOf(t)
kind := v.Kind()
// Must be one of these types to be nillable
return (kind == reflect.Ptr ||
    kind == reflect.Interface ||
    kind == reflect.Slice ||
    kind == reflect.Map ||
    kind == reflect.Chan ||
    kind == reflect.Func) &&
    v.IsNil()
}
```